# How to run c++ and c together in WinRT project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I have a file name as sqlite3.c and some c++ file use to work with the function write in sqlite3.c. But I face a problem to compile the file using visual studio 2012. I create a WindowsRuntimeComponent project for the c++ file and c file. When I set Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As -> "Compile as C++ Code (/TP)", I get an error which is error D8045: cannot compile C file 'xxx.c' with the /clr option.

After that, I change Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As -> "Compile as C Code (/TC)", I get an error which is error D8045: cannot compile C file 'xxx.cpp' with the /clr option.

I don't have an idea to solve this problem. Can anyone give me a help? Thank you.

Comment: Seems you are trying to compile native code with the managed CLR, this won't work!

Comment: So, what should I do to solve this problem.

Comment: Check what VS does to compile and link your program. You can do this in your project-properties. What exactly I can't tell you, though. I have no Win 8 around right now.